# Metrization and uniformity

Tags: general-topology

When I was reading Kelley's *General Topology*, I saw the following on p.186 (6.14 Note):

"... and the result they [Alexandroff and Urysohn] state is (approximately): a topological Hausdorff space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is metrizable iff
there is a uniformity with a countable base such that T is the uniform topology."

Is this an accurate rephrase of their original claims? Or put it another way, is the above statement really true?

I can understand the theorem right before (6.13 Theorem):

"A uniform space is pseudo-metrizable if and only if its uniformity has a countable base"

or its Hausdorff version:

"a uniform space is metrizable iff it is Hausdorff and its uniformity has a countable base"

but I am not sure the form in 6.13 is the same as that in 6.14.

More specifically, 6.14 seems to claim that every metrizable space has a countable base (by the "only if" part), which is not true.

Did I misunderstand anywhere? Or Kelley happened to be inaccurate here -- he did say "... (approximately) ...", so there is an
excuse for inaccuracy.

Comment: Here they talk about base of the *uniformity*, which is something totally different from a base of a topology.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks @Ulli.  So does "uniformity has a countable base" imply that the induced topology is *first* countable?

Comment: Yes, but not vice versa.